# Jaxb fails to parse XML after moving to java 8

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I Am making to move to java 8, and in the process jaxb fails to parse an xml configuration.

While changing nothing but the JDK, the same code and file is successfully parsed using java 7, but does not parse correctly on java 8.

Note that there is no exception thrown but the data does not appear in the object that the xml is unmarshald into.

Any ideas what might cause this very annoying failure.

Comment: Can you post details about your XML and object model?

Comment: Without your object model we can only guess. If you moved from java 6, than the list and map handling has changed.

Comment: I found the cause I will post the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the cause of the problem.

I have not researched the code, but it seems that the code behind JAXB or SAX parser has changed from java7 to 8, and is less forgiving in java 8.
(This might also be due to changes in compiler/jvm itself )

The parsing was done with annotations. and it was something that looks like the following:

> ```
> @XmlRootElement(name = "component_configuration")
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
> public class ComponentConfiguration extends Configuration {}
>
> @XmlRootElement(name="configuration")
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
> public class Configuration {}
> ```

In the java 7 version this kind of "game" was either permitted of was successfully parsed (by luck if you ask me) but in java 8 it didn't work any more.

I ended writing the model again correctly and everything worked fine.

Hope this will help someone else thats braking balls over jaxb compatibility.

Comment: Can you explain your answer further, I don't see anything wrong with what mappings you've shown.

Comment: there is an inheritance between the classes, and each one of them is mapped to a a different root element, when i broke the inheritance it worked out.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.  Were you getting the correct subtype for the root class when you unmarshalled?  Was it just the properties that weren't unmarshalled (all, only inherited, only those on subtype)?  Which version of the Java 8 JDK were you using?

Comment: the root "component_configuration" was parsed, all of its children of type "configuration" were not,, java version 1.8.0.25

Comment: Thanks, I will forward this on to the JAXB reference implementation lead.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another difference between handling Jaxb on Java 7 versus Java 8. I've reduced the issue to a simplified example. (changed the categories so it's non-work-related etc) 
When the setter for a List is called by the Unmarshaller:

- when run in Java 7 the setter will be called with data in the List
- when run in Java 8 the setter will be called only with an empty List object which apparently gets populated later in the unmarshalling process.

The difference I experience is that I must not have the setter do any processing on the List, but rather have a process that is invoked only after the overall object is unmarshalled. 
Or to sum it up, "don't do any processing in the setter".
I've posted the revised example in the question at [Difference in JAXB Java 7 versus Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361075/difference-in-jaxb-java-7-versus-java-8)

Comment: Looking into this further raises the question - is the recommended practice for coding List accessors to omit the Setter altogether when coding JaxB as JaxB seems to do handle the List via the Getter anyway? (and probably there are other alternatives that are recommended)?

Comment: I've reposted this with a more-simplified code example, as a separate question. I'll remove the code example here because I think the version in the new qeustion will be easier to bring into a typical IDE.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361075/difference-in-jaxb-java-7-versus-java-8